# How do I check the capture date of an iPhone MOV file without copying off of Google Drive

Tags: ios, iphone, google-drive-api, exif, quicktime

I have MOV video files on Google Drive which are taken by an iPhone.
I want to check when these videos were captured.

I know this is possible since MOV files taken by iPhones have tags embedded in them with this data.
http://www.csitech.co.uk/iphone-video-metadata/

Unfortunately though the Google Drive API exposes capture dates for photos, it does not for videos. Probably because capture date metadata is not as universally standardized as it is for photos (EXIF).

So I need to run custom code to check the tag, but I don't want to have to copy the file off of Google Drive every time I want to do this.
That is, I want to run the code on Google Drive.

Is this possible?

Comment: It would be helpful to know which programming language and/or client library you are using to make the request to the Drive API.

Comment: I haven't implemented anything yet, I was using the Drive WebUI to test various API calls. I will try implementing your suggestion below in Python and give the Hachoir library a shot (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/hachoir-metadata/)

Answer (score 1):

When retrieving the file contents through the Drive API, you can request a *portion* of the file by providing a `Range:` header, e.g. `Range: bytes=0-100` to retrieve the first 100 bytes of the file.  So you should be able to retrieve just the bytes which make up the header of the .MOV file.

(The method for adding a `Range:` header to your API call will vary, depending on which programming language and/or client library you are using.)

Comment: Thanks, I give this a whirl and see if this accomplishes what I'm trying to do!